# How to convert a string from a template?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There are lines:

```
echo "1111111111111; 2222222222; 8; 2; 34,12,2,3,5,1; UNKNOW;"
```

or

```
echo "1111111111111; 2222222222; 8; 2; 34,12,2,3,5,1,5,12,45,34; UNKNOW;"
```

or

```
echo "1111111111111; 2222222222; 8; 2; 3; UNKNOW;"
```

How to take the value of the last character ";" and to the last comma ","?

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract from string?

Comment: The values contained after the last character  ";" and to the last comma ",".

Example: echo "1111111111111; 2222222222; 8, 2, 34,12,2,3,5,1,5,12,45,34; UNKNOW;"

It is necessary to obtain the values of "8, 2, 34,12,2,3,5,1,5,12,45,34"

Comment: Split the string using cut by `;` and `,` and select right fields separately. Then you can concatenate the two output into one.

Comment: And if you convert to an array through AWK and output as the array elements? What will work faster?

Comment: I found the solution! But not quite understand how it work:


echo "1111111111111;2222222222;8;2;3,1;UNKNOW;" | awk -F';' '{print $5}'

3,1

Comment: If you always have five fields, that is fine, but with arbitrary number of fields in which you always want the last you should use $NF instead of $5

Answer (score 1):

In the comment you showed a solution that satifies you retrieving the 5th field. That is also possible with

```
echo "${line}" | cut -d ";" -f5
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`: `-F` param is for field delimiter/separator, `$5` - fifth field separated by delimited defined in `-F` param:

```
$ echo "1111111111111;2222222222;8;2;3,1;UNKNOW;" | awk -F';' '{print $5}'
3,1
```

---

With `cut`: `-d` param is for field delimiter/separator, `-f5` - fifth field separated by delimited defined in `-d` param:

```
$ echo "1111111111111;2222222222;8;2;3,1;UNKNOW;" | cut -d ';' -f5
3,1
```

---

Out of context but you can use this to get some chars from string: `-c1,2,3,25-30` - cut the chars 1,2,3,25,26,27,28,29,30

```
echo "1111111111111;2222222222;8;2;3,1;UNKNOW;" | cut -c1,2,3,25-30
111;8;2;3
```